# Register only ReferencesMap in csvhelper cause an error

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I want to create a only ReferencesMap class.
`CompositeMap` hold references to `AMap` and `BMap`.

When calling

```
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CompositeMap>();
```

I get an error:

```
No members were found in expression '{expression}'.
```

My code:

```
public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ID);
    }
}

public sealed class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Name);
    }
}


public class Composite
{
    public A a { get; set; }
    public B b { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CompositeMap : ClassMap<Composite>
{
    public CompositeMap()
    {
        References<AMap>(m => m.a);
        References<BMap>(m => m.b);
    }
}
```

Any idea why?
How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.  I tried with that code and it works for me.  What version of `CsvHelper` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to map down an object graph is to do all the mapping in the top node.

```cs
public sealed class CompositeMap : ClassMap<Composite>
{
    public CompositeMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.a.ID);
        Map(m => m.b.Name);
    }
}
```

If you have a specific reason you need to use `References`, let me know and I can update the answer.